# Delete Confirmation JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, dialog

```
echo '<td width="10" align="center"><a href="apagarJogador.php?id_user='.$row['id_user'].' onclick="return confirm(\'Pretende mesmo eliminar este utilizador?\')"><img src="../img/apagar.png" /></a></td>';
```

When I click delete, the confirmation does not appear in javascript.

I've tried different ways, but it does not.

There is another way to do?

Comment: a ending `"` is missing for `href`

Comment: it works, just because of a parenthesis, baah. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a global function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_delete() {
  return confirm('Pretende mesmo eliminar este utilizador?');
}
</script>

echo '<td width="10" align="center"><a href="apagarJogador.php?id_user='.$row['id_user'].' onclick="return confirm_delete()"><img src="../img/apagar.png" /></a></td>';
```

or

```
echo '<td width="10" align="center"><a href="apagarJogador.php?id_user='.$row['id_user'].' onclick="javascript:return confirm(\'Pretende mesmo eliminar este utilizador?\')"><img src="../img/apagar.png" /></a></td>';
```

Comment: Note this still doesn't fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what browser you are using your code on
in Internet Explorer the href comes before the on click command, which means the confirmation will never appear there.
In Fire Fox the onclick comes before.
My Suggestion is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmationBox (id_user) {
    if (confirm('Pretende mesmo eliminar este utilizador?')) {
        alert('confirmed');
        //window.location.href = 'apagarJogador.php?id_user=' + id_user;
    }
    }
</script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="10" align="center"> <a href="#" onclick="return ConfirmationBox ('aaa')"><img src="../img/apagar.png" />kkk</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>
```

you can check following [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VGvs2Qi3o6oIFi5UbTML?p=preview)